# Как работать с разными типами писем?

Tags: python, tkinter, imap

Я пишу приложения для работы с почтой, в моем случае в гугл почтой. Я столкнулся с проблемой, что письма имеют разный Content-Type (text/plain, text/html и т.д.). Вопрос в том, как работать с разными типами писем ( брать из них необходимые данные, тело письма, заголовок... ). Но на сколько я понял, способы взятия этих данных из разных типов писем отличается. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Да, вы все верно поняли. Из письма *plain text* можно читать сразу же, для *html* понадобится парсер вроде `lxml.html` или `BeautifulSoup`. Получаете *Content-Type* письма и на его основе выполняете различную обработку.

Comment: Можно наоборот: сначала приводить все письма к одному типу (допустим, *html*), а потом делать обработку только этого типа.